# Converting time stored as INT to VARCHAR in Presto

Tags: sql, sql-server, presto

I'm pulling data from a Presto DB into a SQL Server table that contains a field called `scan_time`, which stores time values in INT format. The values are obviously not a fixed length, so something like `1233` actually means `00:12:33`.

What is the best way to cast this as a VARCHAR, such that the value `1223` outputs as `00:12:33`?

Comment: How do you know 1133 is 00:11:33 or 01:01:33 or 11:00:33?

Comment: @TanveerBadar if it were any of your alternative examples there would be trailing zeroes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can convert to a time using:

```
select convert(time, stuff(right(concat('0', scan_time), 4), 3, 0, ':'))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1dedc5da738e9fe115a8e2a2f48e6af) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the response - that doesn't work in presto. Maybe I'll have to do the conversions outside the openquery.

Comment: @Cam . . . Your question is pretty clear that the destination database is SQL Server.  If you need to do this in Presto, can you ask another question and make that clear?

Comment: Based on your answer, I've decided to do the formatting on the SQL side, which is why I marked your answer as accepted. Thanks